# What is best practice for versioning SPD workflows/forms?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath

Is there a recommended best practice for utilizing version control (SCM) when creating or modifying workflows or InfoPath forms from within SharePoint Designer 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any good way of versioning workflows that I am aware of, however, for Forms you could use the Form Templates library on the site.  Turn on versioning for that library and publish all of your forms there...